# Javascript not being called after loading

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I have a few javascript routines that I need to run with my application. When I run the application and go to view source, I see the javascript file import, and when I click on it, I am taken to the javascript file, so I know it is being brought down to the client. Right now, I have a simple alert in the beginning of the method I am calling, but that isn't even happening, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Does this look like the correct way to call the javascript when the button is clicked?

```
<p><input type="button" value="Add File" onclick="go();" /></p>
```

Here is the javascript file:

```
var typeAId= 0;
var typeBId= 0;

function addNewDocument(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;
    p.appendChild(newElement);
}

function go(){
    alert('ok');
}

function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function addNewDocument(input) {
    var fileToRemove = 'file-';
    alert('ok');
    var elementName = null;
    if(input === 'formAInput'){
        elementName = 'formA[]';
        typeAId++;
        fileToRemove = fileToRemove+typeAId;
    } else {
        elementName = 'formB[]';
        typeBId++;
        fileToRemove = fileToRemove+typeBId;
    }
    var html = '<input type="file" name="'+elementName+'" /> ' +
               '<a href="" onclick="removeElement('+fileToRemove+'); return false;">Remove</a>';
    if(input === 'formAInput'){}
        addElement('typeAFilesDiv', 'p', 'file-' + typeAId, html);
    } else {
        addElement('typeBFilesDiv', 'p', 'file-' + typeBId, html);
    }
    alert('end');
}
```

Here is how I am importing the javascript:

```
<script src="/js/myJS.js"></script>
```

The js directory is located under the 'war' directory in my Google App Engine Project.
When I click the button, I do not see an alert.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Use something like firebug (Firefox) to find out what is going wrong

Comment: Your question needs more details. It is impossible to answer in its current state.

Comment: Please provide some more code or information, it is incomplete or we are not able to understand what you mean to say, it will be batter if you will make fiddle of your problem so that we can get easily and can let you know solution more quickly

Answer (score 1):

Additional documentation, code, and screenshots would help the community answer more holistically. However, **to answer your most basic question, yes**, that is the correct way to use the `onclick` attribute.

I hypothesize that the JavaScript `addFile` function is not doing what you want it to or something is wrong with the `document.ready` event.